# how can i add js with ng-view and execute immediately angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes, ng-view

for e.g
in my angular app

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
   $routeProvider.when('/login', {
       templateUrl: '../login',
       controller: 'loginCtrl'
}).otherwise(...));
```

in this case my logictrl is in another js file. i want to include this when my path is /login. 
but this show loginCtrl is not a function.after some google i got loginCtrl js is not executed by ng-view.

how can i solve this. please help thankx in advance

Comment: generally you just add all other js files straight away in your index.html to avoid issues like this

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Lazy Loading. A google search should get you started, but here is the first link I found: http://www.slideshare.net/nirkaufman/angularjs-lazy-loading-techniques

Their technique is to use RequireJS.